# installing Python bigfloat module

Tags: python, macos, bigfloat

I'm trying to get the bigfloat Python package onto my mac, but I'm not very good at this sort of thing.

I have downloaded the latest package as described [here](http://packages.python.org/bigfloat/#module-bigfloat). The documentation says:

```
In order to use the bigfloat package you will need to have both the GMP and MPFR libraries already installed on your system.
```

I think that the GMP and MPFR libraries are already installed on my system - at least when I search for them I see folders with their names and files in them.

When I try to install bigfloat by typing:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get lots of error messages. The first ones being:

```
src/mpfr.c:223:17: error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
src/mpfr.c:224:18: error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory
```

The gmp.h and mpfr.h files are on my computer, but obviously I need to do something else.

Cleary I don't understand how the whole process works, but any pointers in the right direction would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to have installed both the GMP and MPFR libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

Then just run:

```
 sudo pip install bigfloat
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and here's what I've tried as per the readme file in the bigfloat installation directory:

"An example: on Mac OS X, using the system Python, but with MPFR and GMP
installed in /opt/local (e.g., by MacPorts), one can do":

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib CPATH=/opt/local/include python setup.py build
```

This didn't throw any errors, but when I checked to see if it installed by running this test:

```
python -m bigfloat.test.test_bigfloat
```

I got the error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named mpfr
```

You can give this a try to see if it works for you, but I'm still lost.

What you should get if it's a successful installation is this:

```
the bigfloat-0.3.0a1/ directory that you created can now be deleted.
```

Comment: I got bigfloat to install, but only when I decided to change my python  installation (went with anaconda python: http://www.continuum.io/downloads). I did so by doing "pip install bigfloat". This is no solution, but I just wanted to inform you of the pip install option.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble installing python bigfloat on my Mac (v10.10.3) via easy_install and pip and got a similar error problem; it is because bigfloat requires a couple other libraries.

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29977244/1637816)

I installed the gmp & mpfr libraries then pip would install properly

```
pip install bigfloat
```

or

```
pip3.5 install bigfloat
```