# python bigfloat installation issues

Tags: python, mpfr, mpc, gmpy, bigfloat

My Problem is similar to this poster and I'm using a MAC OsX 10.9.5 version:

[python 'bigfloat' package installation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409740/python-bigfloat-package-installation-issues/26298218#26298218)

When I try to install the "mpc-1.0.2" package, it doesn't compile and gives this error:

```
grep: /home/case/local/lib/libgmp.la: No such file or directory
sed: /home/case/local/lib/libgmp.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/home/case/local/lib/libgmp.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[2]: *** [libmpc.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My configure command is :

./configure --prefix=/users/username/local --with-gmp=/users/username/local --with-mpfr=/users/username/local

Can anyone or Casevh help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments.

If your goal is to compile `bigfloat`, then you don't need to compile `gmpy2` or `MPC`. The first part of my instructions were copied from process for compiling `GMP`, `MPFR` and `MPC` for use with `gmpy2`.

In my examples, I usually use my local username `case`, a generic `username`, or occasionally another location. You will need to edit the commands to use the actual location where the files exist.

Both `bigfloat` and `gmpy2` provide access to the `MPFR` library for arbitrary-precision floating point arithmetic. They do use slightly different APIs, especially for controlling the contexts.

`gmpy2` also provides access to the `GMP` library (for arbitrary-precision integer and rational numbers) and to the `MPC`library (for arbitrary-precision complex numbers).

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy` and `gmpy2`.

Comment: @ML_Passion It is failing because the directory `/home/case/local/` does not exist. Where are you actually putting the the files? The options that you pass to `./configure` need to reflect the true location on your system.

Comment: You are right I don't need to compile gmpy2 or MPC for bigfloat. Bigfloat got installed when i tried to put the bigfloat directory in the location where GMP and MPFR were compiled.   But now I need to figure out how to marry numpy and bigfloat, since the need for Bigfloat arose from the warning "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp" and I was using an exponential function for curve-fitting.

Comment: @ML_Passion: Use `gmpy2` rather than `bigfloat`: it's more capable, has more features, and is better maintained.